# Why is my code throwing an error message?

Tags: c#

I am creating a method in C# for changing the visibility of a control, but when I use the switch statement to know what control is wanted, I get an error saying a constant value is needed.

This is my code:

```
public void _Visible(Control sf, bool visible)
{
     switch (sf)
     {
         case panel1:
             break;
     }
}
'''
```

I expect it to let me use it in this way

```
_Visible(RichTextBox, true);
```

Comment: Read the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch), or read the error message: **a constant value is needed**.  ACCEPTABLE: `case 1:`, `case IEnumerable<object> subList:`,  or `case DayOfWeek.Monday:`.  SUGGESTION: If you really want to branch on "panel1" vs. "something else", perhaps an if/else block might be your best bet.

Comment: could you suggest me a solution?

Comment: public void _Visible( Control ctrl, bool value ) { ctrl.VIsible = value }

Comment: on your purpose, it'll be an answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `panel1`?  Presumably it's a property in your class which represents a `Control` on your form.  The error is telling you it's not a compile-time constant, which would indeed be the case for properties/variables/etc.

If its value can vary then the compiler can't guarantee that the `switch` structure would be valid.  Which it needs to be able to guarantee in order to generate the executable code.

You'd either need to use a constant value or replace your `switch` structure with an `if/else if` structure.  For example:

```
public void _Visible(Control sf,bool visible)
{
    if (sf == panel1) // or ReferenceEquals() ?
    {
        // do something
    }
    else if (sf == panel2)
    {
        // do something else
    }
    // etc.
}
```

`switch` isn't *always* a direct replacement for `if/else if` structures.  There's considerably more information in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch), including the "type pattern" and "when clause" and other useful constructs for a `switch`.

Comment: Yep, Panel1 is a Control in my windows form and right my switch statement is not working as you said I will replace it with if/else if.